# Let $f: W \rightarrow X$ & $g: W \rightarrow X$ be cont. functions. Prove that if $X$ is Hausdorff then $c(f,g)$ is closed in $W$.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

> Let $W, V$ be topological spaces, and let $f: W \rightarrow X$ and $g: W \rightarrow X$ be continuous functions. Define the coincidence set of $f$ & $g$ to be the subset $$c(f,g) = \{w \in W | f(w) = g(w)\}$$ of $W$. Prove that if $X$ is Hausdorff then $c(f,g)$ is closed in $W$.

Define $\bar{c}(f,g) = \{(w_1, w_2) \in W \times W | w_1, w_2 \in c(f,g)\}$.

Suppose that $X$ is Hausdorff. Consider the function $\phi := f \times g: W \times W \rightarrow X \times X$. Then $\phi(\bar{c(f,g)}) = \{(f(w),g(w')) | w, w' \in c(f,g) \}$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, it is also T1. So each $(f(w), g(w)) \in \phi(\bar{c(f,g)})$ is closed. Since the union of closed sets is closed, $\phi(\bar{c(f,g)})$ must be closed.

Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $f \times g$ is also continuous. So $\phi(\bar{c(f,g)})$ closed in $X \times X$ $\implies$ $\phi^{-1}\phi(\bar{c(f,g)})$ is closed in $W \times W$.

Then I showed that $\bar{c}(f,g) = \phi^{-1}\phi(c(f,g))$. So $c(f,g)$ must be closed in $W$.

Do you think my approach is correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Since the union of closed sets is closed" Only unions of _finitely many_ closed sets must be closed. Consider $h\colon w \mapsto (f(w),g(w))$ and use the fact that $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal in $X \times X$ is closed.

Comment: In a Hausdorff space (or $T_1$, for that matter), *every* subset is a union of closed sets, namely of singletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have pointed out in comments the main problem with your argument: arbitrary unions of closed sets need not be closed. There is a proof using your function $\varphi$ and the fact that since $X$ is Hausdorff, the diagonal in $X\times X$ is closed, but you can also simply show directly that $W\setminus c(f,g)$ is open.

HINT: Suppose that $w\in W\setminus c(f,g)$; then $f(w)\ne g(w)$. $X$ is Hausdorff, so there are open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ such that $f(w)\in U$, $g(w)\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$; now consider the set $f^{-1}[U]\cap g^{-1}[V]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$, and sincce $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $f^{-1}[U]$ and $g^{-1}[V]$ must be open in $W$. Suppose that $f^{-1}[U] \cap g^{-1}[V] \not= \emptyset$, then $\exists w \in W$ such that $f(w) \in U,V$. But then $U \cap V \not= \emptyset$, a contradiction, right?

Comment: However, I'm still confused with the other method (using $\phi$). Since $X$ is Hausdorff, we know that $\Delta X$ (the diagonal in $X \times X$) is closed. Since $\phi$ is continuous, $\phi^{-1}(\Delta X)$ must be closed in $W$. Obviously $\{(w,w)| w \in c(f,g)\} \subseteq \phi^{-1}(\Delta X)$. However, we cannot conclude that the reverse inclusion is true, because there could be $w \not= w'$ such that $f(w) = g(w')$, right? But in that case, $c(f,g)$ is only a subset of a closed set...and I can't really see how to conclude that $c(f,g)$ would be closed in $W$...

Comment: @Artus: I’m afraid not; the argument isn’t even set up to be a proof by contradiction. It’s a direct proof that $W\setminus c(f,g)$ is open, so we’re trying to find an open nbhd of $w$ that is contained in $W\setminus c(f,g)$. Let $G=f^{-1}[U]\cap g^{-1}[V]$; you know that the original point $w$ is in $G$, so you already know that $G\ne\varnothing$, and in fact that $G$ is an open nbhd of $w$. Is $G\subseteq W\setminus c(f,g)$? If $y\in G$, then $f(y)\in U$ and $g(y)\in V$; what does that tell you about $f(y)$ and $g(y)$?

Comment: @Artus: For the second comment, I misread your $\varphi$; it isn’t quite what you want. You want $$h:W\to X\times X:w\mapsto\langle f(w),g(w)\rangle\;.$$ Then what is $h^{-1}[\Delta_X]$?

Comment: Thanks again. I think I forgot what I was trying to prove. Anyways, so if we have $y \in G$, then $f(y) \in U$ and $g(y) \in V$. If $f(y)=g(y)$, then $U \cap V \not= \emptyset$. So $f(y) \not= g(y) \implies y \in W$ \ $c(f,g)$, right? Since the open set $f^{-1}[U] \cap g^{-1}[V]$ is contained entirely in $W$ \ $c(f,g)$, $W$ \ $c(f,g)$ must be an open set, implying that $c(f,g)$ must be closed, right?

Comment: @Artus: Yes, that’s the argument that I had in mind.

Comment: First we need to show that $h$ is continuous. But this is immediate from the continuity of $f$ and $g$. Then, since $\Delta X$ is closed in $X \times X$, $h^{-1}(\Delta X)$ is closed in W. Of course, we have $c(f,g) \subseteq h^{-1}(\Delta X)$. We need to prove the converse. Let $ w \in h^{-1}(\Delta X)$. Then $f(w)=g(w)$. By definition, $w \in c(f,g)$. So $c(f,g) = h^{-1}(\Delta X)$ and it must be closed in $W$. I was trying to use $\phi : W \times W \rightarrow X \times X$ because that's what the hint told us...but I guess that was a typo or something. Do you think this is correct?

Comment: @Artus: And that’s the other argument, the one that Daniel Fischer was suggesting in his comment on the question.